# VBA – Alteration in a code

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code which performs different checks for 3 different columns. It works absolutely fine, but I want some alteration. Let’s see the code first.

```
Sub test()
On Error Resume Next

Dim cel As Range

Dim colCStr As String, colDStr As String, colEStr As String

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
With ws
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.count, "C").End(xlUp).row
    For Each cel In .Range("C2:C" & LastRow)
        'condition for Column C (cell not empty & characters in cell are alphabet)
        For i = 1 To Len(cel)
        If Not (Not IsEmpty(cel) And Asc(UCase(cel)) > 64 And Asc(UCase(cel)) < 91) Then
                colCStr = colCStr & "," & cel.row
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
        'condition for Column D (cell is numeric & length of cell value is 2 or 3)
        If Not (IsNumeric(cel.Offset(0, 1)) And (Len(cel.Offset(0, 1)) = 2 Or Len(cel.Offset(0, 1)) = 3)) Then
            colDStr = colDStr & "," & cel.Offset(0, 1).row
        End If
        'condition for Column E (cell is numeric & length of cell value is 7 or 8 or cell value is 0)
        If Not (IsNumeric(cel.Offset(0, 2)) And (Len(cel.Offset(0, 2)) = 7 Or Len(cel.Offset(0, 2)) = 8) Or cel.Offset(0, 2) = 0) Then
            colEStr = colEStr & "," & cel.Offset(0, 2).row
        End If
    Next cel
End With
'disply message box only if there's error
If Len(colCStr) > 0 Then
Sheets("Error_sheet").Range("A2" & row).Value = "Errors in Column C" & " : " & Mid(colCStr, 2, Len(colAStr))
If Len(colDStr) > 0 Then
Sheets("Error_sheet").Range("B2" & row).Value = "Errors in Column D" & " : " & Mid(colDStr, 2, Len(colDStr))
If Len(colEStr) > 0 Then
Sheets("Error_sheet").Range("C2" & row).Value = "Errors in Column E" & " : " & Mid(colEStr, 2, Len(colEStr))
Else
End If
End If


End Sub
```

The code performs following checks:

**Column `C`:** Cell not empty & characters in cell are alphabet (Actually I don’t want to perform any checks over here in Column `C`, but if I delete the lines of code which validate Column `C` the rest of code stops getting executed too).

**Column `D`:** Cell is numeric & length of cell value is `2` or `3` (I want the absolutely same checks).

**Column `E`:** Cell is numeric & length of cell value is `7` or `8` or **cell value** is `0` (I want the absolutely same checks).

I appreciate your time and efforts.

Comment: Yeah i have worked but not that much. I tried but its bit tricky for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This version doesn't use Offset so it should be easier to update (and more efficient)

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CheckColDandE()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, lr As Long, arr As Variant, r As Long
    Dim dOk As Boolean, eOk As Boolean, dErr As String, eErr As String

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    arr = ws.Range("D2:E" & lr)

    For r = 1 To lr - 1

        dOk = IsNumeric(arr(r, 1)) And arr(r, 1) > 9 And arr(r, 1) < 1000

        eOk = IsNumeric(arr(r, 2))
        eOk = eOk And (arr(r, 2) > 999999 And arr(r, 2) < 100000000 Or arr(r, 2) = 0)

        If Not dOk Then dErr = dErr & r + 1 & ", "
        If Not eOk Then eErr = eErr & r + 1 & ", "
    Next

    With ws.Range("D" & lr + 1 & ":E" & lr + 1)
        .Value2 = vbNullString
        If Len(dErr) > 0 Then .Cells(1) = "Rows with Errors: " & Left(dErr, Len(dErr) - 2)
        If Len(eErr) > 0 Then .Cells(2) = "Rows with Errors: " & Left(eErr, Len(eErr) - 2)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help !! @paul bica. i this code is not giving desired output and that too taking too much of time. FIY i want to validate column 'D' and 'E' only  Column D: Cell is numeric & length of cell value is 2 or 3 (I want the absolutely same checks).

Column E: Cell is numeric & length of cell value is 7 or 8 or cell value is 0 (I want the absolutely same checks).

Comment: No checks should be performed in column 'C'. and to be honest the offset method is pretty faster than this newly written code by you. Could you please do the same using offset method if possible and if any of the cells is blank that is absolutely fine(Blanks must be skipped by the code in both the columns )

Comment: With some minor changes its what i was seeking. Now its working beautifully. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the following lines (and update your comments! The column names in comments and code ae not the same):

```
    'condition for Column A (cell not empty & characters in cell are alphabet)
    For i = 1 To Len(cel)
    If Not (Not IsEmpty(cel) And Asc(UCase(cel)) > 64 And Asc(UCase(cel)) < 91) Then
            colCStr = colCStr & "," & cel.row
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
```

Comment: ya i have changed the column names now.